# How do I write a BLOB, any BLOB to sqlite?

Tags: objective-c, python-2.7, sqlite, pyobjc

I need to write an Obj-C object (e.g. NSString in this case) to a sqlite database and store it in a BLOB column, using Python 2.7.
To that extent I wrote this demo code that fails with the below traceback.

```py
    from sqlite3 import connect
    from Foundation import NSArchiver

    conn = connect(':memory:')
    create = "CREATE TABLE test(data BLOB)"
    conn.execute(create)
    conn.commit()

    blob = NSArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject_("Hello World").bytes()
    print type(blob), blob
    sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)"
    data = [blob]

    conn.execute(sql, data)
    conn.commit()
```

This traces back with:

```sh
    $ ./sqlite3_test.py
    <type 'memoryview'> <memory at 0x104a5e218>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./sqlite3_test.py", line 16, in <module>
        conn.execute(sql, data)
    sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

No amount of magik using `sqlite3.Binary` (which is defined as `Binary = buffer` inside the sqlite3 module) or `.tobytes()` (from [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=memoryview#memoryview)) made that work any better.

I also tried to create a [buffer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer) object out of the NSArchiver blob, but a naïve approach:

```py
b = buffer(blob, 0, len(blob))
```

traces back with `TypeError: buffer object expected` - arguably NSArchiver objects are not Python strings.

Comment: If you're using Objective C, you can probably use the native Sqlite C interface, and thus the [blob api](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) (Use the [zeroblob()](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#zeroblob) function in an `INSERT` and then the C functions to fill it in with the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working example!
On the Objective-C call `bytes()` I need to call the memoryview `.tobytes()` which can then be serialized to `buffer()`.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

from sqlite3 import connect, Binary
from Foundation import NSArchiver

conn = connect(':memory:')
create = "CREATE TABLE test(data BLOB)"
conn.execute(create)
conn.commit()

str = NSString.alloc().initWithString_("Hello World")
blob = NSArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject_(str).bytes().tobytes()
print "Original (%s): %s" % (len(blob), blob)
sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)"
data = [Binary(blob)]

conn.execute(sql, data)
conn.commit()

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for r in rows:
    print "In database (%s): %s" % (len(r[0]), r[0])
```

This gives:

```shell
$ ./sqlite3_test.py 
Original (84):
   streamtyped???@???OC_PythonString?NSString?NSObject??i?+
                                                                Hello World?
In database (84):
   streamtyped???@???OC_PythonString?NSString?NSObject??i?+
                                                                Hello World?
```